# styled-system props typing with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm using [styled-system](https://github.com/jxnblk/styled-system) and one key of the library is to use the shorthand props to allow easy and fast theming.

I've simplified my component but here is the interesting part:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { color, ColorProps } from 'styled-system'

const StyledDiv = styled('div')<ColorProps>`
  ${color}
`

const Text = ({ color }: ColorProps) => {
  return <StyledDiv color={color} />
}
```

I have an error on the `color` prop which says:

> Type 'string | (string | null)[] | undefined' is not assignable to
>   type 'string | (string & (string | null)[]) | undefined'.

I think that's because `styled-system` use the same naming as the native HTML attribute `color` and it conflicts.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

`color` seems to be declared in react's declaration file under `HTMLAttributes` - it's not exported.

I had to work around this by creating a [custom prop](https://styled-system.com/custom-props/)

Example is using `@emotion/styled` but also works with `styled-components`

```
// component.js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { style, ResponsiveValue } from 'styled-system';
import CSS from 'csstype';

const textColor = style({
  prop: 'textColor',
  cssProperty: 'color',
  key: 'colors'
});


type Props = {
  textColor?: ResponsiveValue<CSS.ColorProperty>
}

const Box = styled.div<Props>`
  ${textColor};
`

export default Box;
```

```
// some-implementation.js
import Box from '.';

const Page = () => (
  <Box textColor={['red', 'green']}>Content in a box</Box>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to only happen when you pass the prop down from an ancestor/parent component to a custom component rather than directly to the "styled" component. I found a discussion about it in the [styled-components GitHub issues](https://github.com/styled-system/styled-system/issues/1206#issuecomment-1014609863). Following the thread from there there is discussion of utilising [transient props](https://medium.com/@probablyup/introducing-transient-props-f35fd5203e0c) and their ultimate inclusion in [styled-components v5.1](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/2093).

This however didn't seem to solve the problem completely in my case.

The problem appears to be due to the component in question returning an HTML div element and so it is extended correctly (by React.HTMLAttributes) to include `color: string | undefined` as a DOM attribute for that element. This is of course not compatible with `ColorProps` hence the error. Styled-components filters out a whitelist that includes `color` however this won't happen in your custom or HOC.

This can be resolved in a number of ways, but the cleanest seems to be adding `as?: React.ElementType` to your type definition.

In this case:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { color, ColorProps } from 'styled-system'

interface Props extends ColorProps { as?: React.ElementType }

const StyledDiv = styled('div')<Props>`
  ${color}
`

const Text = ({ color }: Props) => {
  return <StyledDiv color={color} />
}
```

This way the extension by `React.HTMLAttributes` is replaced by `React.ElementType` and so there is no longer a conflict with the `color` DOM attribute.

This also solves problems with passing `SpaceProps`.

### NOTE:

It appears [styled-system](https://github.com/styled-system/styled-system) has been unceremoniously abandoned. There are a few [open](https://github.com/styled-system/styled-system/issues/1547) [issues](https://github.com/styled-system/styled-system/issues/1986) about what is being used to replace it. My recommendation after a little deliberation is [system-ui/theme-ui](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui). It seems to be the closest direct replacement and has a few contributors in common with `styled-system`.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the answer. Good explanation and a succinct resolution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ColorProps`, try using `color: CSS.ColorProperty` (`import * as CSS from 'csstype');  Here is a gist showing how I'm creating some a typed "Box" primitive with typescript/styled-system: https://gist.github.com/chiplay/d10435c0962ec62906319e12790104d1

Good luck!

Comment: Doesn't this opt out of the ability to use styled-system's responsive array values for the color prop?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use Typescript cast capabilities and keep styled-system logic intact. e.g.:

```js
const Heading: React.FC<ColorProps> = ({ color, children }) => {
  return <HeadingContainer color={(color as any)} {...props}>{children}</HeadingContainer>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [xuanlopez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711454/styled-system-props-typing-with-typescript/66258458#answer-62572426)' answer - not sure what issue the 5.0.0 release specifically resolves - but using `$color` as the renamed prop rather than `textColor` designates it as a [transient prop](https://medium.com/@probablyup/introducing-transient-props-f35fd5203e0c) in styled components so as a prop it won't appear in the rendered DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Building on Chris' answer, and using the latest docs on on [custom props](https://styled-system.com/custom-props).

```
// core/constants/theme.ts
// Your globally configured theme file
export const theme = { colors: { primary: ['#0A43D2', '#04122B'] } }

// core/constants/styledSystem.ts
import {
  color as ssColor,
  ColorProps as SSColorProps,
  TextColorProps,
  compose,
  system,
} from 'styled-system'

// Styled-system patch for the color prop fixing "Types of property 'color' are incompatible"
// when appling props to component that extend ColorProps.
export interface ColorProps extends Omit<SSColorProps, 'color'> {
  textColor?: TextColorProps['color']
}

export const color = compose(
  ssColor,
  system({
    // Alias color as textColor
    textColor: {
      property: 'color',
      // This connects the property to your theme, so you can use the syntax shown below E.g "primary.0".
      scale: 'colors'
    }
  })
)

// components/MyStyledComponent.ts
import { color, ColorProps } from 'core/constants/styledSystem.ts'

interface MyStyledComponentProps extends ColorProps {}

export const MyStyledComponent = styled.div<MyStyledComponentProps>`
  ${color}
`

// components/MyComponent.ts
export const MyComponent = () => <MyStyledComponent textColor="primary.0">...
```

---

**EDIT: updating to styled-components ^5.0.0 fixes this**

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v500---2020-01-13